# Передача нескольких переменных в {% include 'index.html'%} django

Tags: python, django

Как можно передать переменные через with?

```
{% include "index.html" with stats='name'%}
```

Можно указывать все через пробел, но тогда строка слишком большая и при переносе строки, все ломается

Comment: Вам позволяет возможность разбить код на несколько html файлов? [пример](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/include-django-template-tags/)

Answer (score 0):

*Возможно это поможет:*

1. [Django Template: Passing a variable from an include, into a dot notated path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49603672/4827341)
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/  (тут просто найдите описание тега include, там про это детально рассказано)

Comment: лучше приводить ссылку на оригинал, а не на сайт с результатами работы автопередводчика.